# Remove setting default link on tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a proplem with tomcat 7.
When I setting `<a href="google.com">` then on brower when hover this link it is display as the bellow :

> localhost:8080/AppName/google.com

Please show me locate where is setting `"localhost:8080/AppName"`.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the absolute url instead of just google.com. It's not because of tomcat, is the browser. When creating a hyperlink you need to set the absolute url or relative (just the path to append to where you're currently). In your case you want to set it to full URL https://www.google.com

When it's relative, it'll go to http://yourserver.com/currenturl/newrelativeurl

```
<a href="https://www.google.com"></a> //Absolute

<a href="google.com"></a> //Relative
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Please upvote and mark the question as resolved if my answer was helpful so that other users can see it in the future.